# How to debug processes running inside docker-compose with pycharm

Tags: docker, pycharm, docker-compose

I'm trying to switch my local Pycharm + Django to docker based dev env. I run on mac and use Docker-Compose (few dockers: my django app, some db and nginx).

All runs fine, code change immediately reflected in docker and correct packages available while coding in Pycharm. Once docker-compose started, a list of running containers is shown in Pycharm's docker plugin window, for each container i can see its log/properties/port/volume bindings.

Interpreter seems to be configured properly with Docker Compose(app at [{my path}/docker-compose.yaml]) as project interpreter and path mapping for ->/code to the correct folder in docker.

The problem is I don't manage to debug it. When i select Docker-Compose in debug dialog the only option available is Run, not Debug.

[image]

It doesn't look to me as Docker/Compose issue, but Pycharm plugin which doesn't let to run in debug with docker-compose run/debug configuration.

Any idea how to debug it with Pycharm?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are supposed to use standard Python run configuration, no the Docker-specific one. The latter is used to build containers, start docker-compose services and so on.

PyCharm will auto-start your services, mount your code and execute it inside a container with pure Python Run Configuration if a Docker-based interpreter is selected.

Perhaps the docs can help: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html

Comment: Where I work, my PC is fairly locked down, all the dev code runs in docker - and I have pycharm outside.   It would be good to be able to debug it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what is stopping you from doing it, did you try setting a docker-based interpreter in PyCharm? Or is it impossible in your particular case?

Answer (score 5):

There is currently a problem running dockerized django with an entry point, so to give an idea of the problem if someone else lands here with that! if you are facing this problem create a different docker-compose.dev.yml file just for debugging without an entry point. This is the work around for now

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by disabling entry point. My follow up question is how do I execute the program without the entry point? Thanks

Comment: by using a command instead, so basically the workaround is to have a dev docker-compose.yml with a command that runs, no entrypoint.sh I mean

Answer (score -1):

Following is a video I created showing different ways to run docker in Pycharm and debug it using Pycharm breakpoints.

https://youtu.be/NMFAkrZTciM

Comment: Your video describes how to simply run the docker compose environment via the IDE. This question is about connecting with a debugger.