# pycharm docker-compose debug

Tags: debugging, docker-compose, pycharm, sanic

I recently started working on a project which uses docker-compose and consists of multiple services, therefore installing and debugging locally has been a problem. I started looking for a way to debug with docker-compose and came across this piece of [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html)

While this explains how to configure an interpreter using Django, I use Sanic for the project and therefore can't follow the tutorial to a T. Could you advice on the template for Run/Debug configuration using docker-compose?

I also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385861/how-to-debug-processes-running-inside-docker-compose-with-pycharm) but it links to the aforementioned documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that most of the documentation should readily work with Sanic, if you only modify the `Dockerfile` slightly:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /app

# By copying over requirements first, we make sure that Docker will cache
# our installed requirements rather than reinstall them on every build
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Now copy in our code, and run it
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Then in `main.py`:

```py
from sanic import Sanic

app = Sanic("MyApp")

# ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a Remote Python Environment with Docker Compose. Very useful for debugging. From `Preferences` -> `Project Interpreter` -> `Add...` -> `Docker Compose`. You should select your Docker Compose file. Afterwards you can simply run/debug your `main.py` by selecting your Remote Python Interpreter (you can select it from your `Run/Debug Configurations`).

PS: I build the docker-compose file before running the application from Pycharm. I have experienced some bugs when I run the compose file directly from Pycharm.

Comment: was only able to run, but not to debug, this way?